# Spring Tomcat архитектура

Tags: java, spring

Задача приложения - работать со сторонним RESTfull сервисом.
Взаимодействие включает в себя обмен JSON сообщениями + по запросу стороннего сервиса, формировать php-страницы.

Для того, чтоб на стороне моего приложения обрабатывать входящие запросы и формировать php-страницы, я настроил Spring web-mvc framework под Tomcat
Соответственно у меня есть контроллер:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class TomcatController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/*")
    public String postEvent(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
       ...
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/*")
    public String getEvent(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
       ...
    }
```

А вот для того, чтоб выполнять исходящие запросы раньше я использовал:

```
WebResource service = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig()).resource("HTTP://...");

        try {

            ClientResponse clientResponse;
            clientResponse = service
                    .queryParams(queryParams)
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);

            String response = clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);
        } catch ()
        ...
```

Вопрос в том, что я бы хотел использовать TomcatController, чтоб обрабатывать ответы на мои запросы. Так как события, которые шлет мне сторонний сервис сам или в ответ на мои запросы - это события одного семейства и я не хочу дублировать точки входя для них.

Скажите как правильно сделать в этом случае? Как инициировать запросы в Сервлете?

Comment: `формировать php-страницы` - такой дичи я еще не видел. Зачем Вам Java вообще? пилите на php. Бразер понимает только html, css и js. Он хз про php и прочие штуки.

Comment: Для исходящий запросов используется `RestTemplate` вместе со српингом. У  `TomcatController`-а можно убрать маппинг. Он один и тот же. `чтоб обрабатывать ответы на мои запросы` - так не работают `http` запросы. Один из выходов из этой ситуации это то что бы тот сервис делал запрос на нужным Вам `url`. А в ответ на Ваш запрос к нему писал просто `200 OK`

Comment: Ну что ж, формирует html-страницы а не php. Я поэтому на Javaи пишу, чтоб не сильно вдаваться в то, что там формируется для браузера.

Comment: А вот за `RestTemplate` спасибо, почитаю. Возможно это то, что нужно.